# DbExpress: Using New 5.1 libmysql.dll with older MySQL 5.0 server

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress, libmysql

I would like to find out from fellow developers if there are any pitfalls in using a recent libmysql.dll with a previous MySQL server. I use Delphi with DbExpress to build database applications.

My main reason is that I have both Delphi 7 and Delphi 2010 on my development machine. I have built applications with D7 that use MySQL 5.0 but D2010 requires MySQL 5.1.

I would like to avoid upgrading all my previous DB applications if I can help it hence would like to keep using MySQL 5.0 server but still develop all new DB applications using D2010.

Your advice and or suggestions on this matter will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar, with D7 and D2010 apps, and suggest you look at it the other way round - move to MySQL 5.1 or later and test your D7 apps to confirm they work. 
(If they don't, add newer version of libmysql.dll (e.g. for MySQL v5.1.8), and make SURE you are not using the "old" libmysql in the windows path (rename all other files and put the new libmysql in your app exe directory.
HTH
Chris

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but am afraid this will not work as the dbExpress driver am using with D7 only supports MySQL 5.0!

Comment: Still worth a try - as long as you dont use any 5.1 features!